# Date Format as 2012-12-20T16:00:00.000Z?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsdateformatter

I'm getting date as 2012-12-24 08:59:00 +0000 and i want it as  2012-12-20T16:00:00.000Z
i tried with this code

```
NSDateComponents *dayComponent = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init] ;
    NSDate* now = [NSDate date];
    NSCalendar *theCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDateFormatter* formatter = [NSDateFormatter alloc];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
    [formatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"UTC"]];
dayComponent.day = -2;
        NSDate* fromDate = [theCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dayComponent toDate:now options:0];
        fromDateStr = [formatter stringFromDate:fromDate];
```

my requirement is to get date of previous days like before 2 days, before 14 days etc in specified format.
but i'm getting `fromDateStr` as empty string.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: when you tried with your above code, what output did you get?

Comment: What do you mean by "date of privies"? You say you're "getting date as [...]" - what do you mean?

Comment: @Prateek empty string i.e. fromDatrStr is empty.

Comment: @JonSkeet i've edited my question actually this is privious days.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The date format for 2012-12-20T16:00:00.000Z is
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'

Hope that helps.

Let me know if that does not give you the desired result.

Here is a sample code that worked for me:

```
 NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"];
    NSString *str = [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
    NSLog(@"Date = %@",str);
```

The output was:

```
Date = 2012-12-26T14:55:36.702Z
```

Comment: Sorry man it didn't help me as i get same result i.e. empty string.

Comment: I am not sure why it did not work for you. Check my edited answer.

Comment: I got it, silly mistake from my side forgot to initialize formatter.Now its working.. Thanks!!